# trouble styling my toolbar and app

Tags: android, android-styles, android-toolbar

I switched my app to use the toolbar and it looks like this now:

[image]

I used a material color picker to pick out colors, so I can make it look more like this:

[image]

The xml I have for those colors looks like this:

```
<color name="primary">#FF9800</color>
    <color name="primary_dark">#F57C00</color>
    <color name="primary_light">#FFE0B2</color>
    <color name="accent">#FFEB3B</color>
    <color name="primary_text">#212121</color>
    <color name="secondary_text">#727272</color>
    <color name="icons">#212121</color>
    <color name="divider">#B6B6B6</color>
```

I tried to throw it into my styles.xml like this, but it had no effect:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

    </style>

    <color name="primary">#FF9800</color>
    <color name="primary_dark">#F57C00</color>
    <color name="primary_light">#FFE0B2</color>
    <color name="accent">#FFEB3B</color>
    <color name="primary_text">#212121</color>
    <color name="secondary_text">#727272</color>
    <color name="icons">#212121</color>
    <color name="divider">#B6B6B6</color>


</resources>
```

My xml layout pre-defines the toolbar but when I took the background color out it just had nothing:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#2196F3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:divider="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:choiceMode="none"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the colors on your theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondary_text</item>
</style>
```

Comment: that changed the color of all the text for the most part. But my toolbar and tabs are still blue.

Comment: Your OS is not Lollipop, right? Are you using Activity or ActionBarActivity?

Comment: Yes, Iam not using lollipop. I changed the background color to my primary and that fixed the toolbar. But the rest of my app like pop ups etc are still blue and black.

Comment: Yeah, material design is not supported by the support library for dialogs. you would have to use something like [afollestad's material dialogs](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs).